# How to linearize the following?

Tags: functions

$$y^2=\frac{π^2\cdot L^2}{3g\cdot x}$$

What should I plot against what to get a linear function (assuming $L$ and $g$ are constants)? I don't know how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Maybe $\frac{1}{y^2}$ against $\frac{1}{x}$? However I don't know how to justify this and I find it hard to check because I don't have numbers to fill in.

Comment: You will get better results if you share details about the course you are taking, and the lesson you received that contains this problem.

Comment: Plot $y^2$ against $ 1/x$. Also almost anything looks straight on log plot because of log scaling.

Answer (score 0):

taking logs we find
$$
2\ln y = \ln \alpha - \ln x
$$
where $\alpha = \frac{\pi^2}{3g}$
thus we can plot
$$
z = -\frac{1}{2}t + \frac{\ln \alpha}{2} = -\frac{1}{2} t + C
$$
where 
$$
z = \ln y\\
t = \ln x.
$$

Comment: I don't think we're supposed to work with such a complicated function. Thanks though!